# Check not null in Java

Tags: java, notnull

Imagine I have, say, XML-generated entity in Java that holds some data I need.
For example:

```
<Car>
   <Engine>
      <Power>
         175
      </Power>
   </Engine>
</Car>
```

So if I need an engine power, I, followed by the best practices of business software development, will do the next thing:

```
Car car = dao.getCar()
Power power = car != null && car.engine != null ? power : null
return power
```

I hate this. Sometimes it seems that half of the code is just null checks.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's the design of your XML...

Comment: I'm going to flag this as "unclear what you are asking."

Comment: potentially, any of these nodes is not present. You can check your xml file against a xsd schema, otherwise you have to do the checks manually.

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää why is this unclear? The question is about how to eliminate boilerplate code.

Comment: Is that valid for a car to not have an engine? Is that valid for an engine to not have a power? If not, then you should not do these null-checks, because the values should never be null, and if they are, you'd better fail early to make the bug obviously apparent, rather than returning null and clutter your code.

Comment: Agree with JB Nizet. It is because my example is bad. Let's imagine the Engine can be null from business point of view.

Comment: @f1sh The way it was titled and phrased, it seemed to me to be a rant about something OP may or may not have designed himself.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [Java 8 Optional class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).
It does exactly that: it avoids the ugly checks on `null`.

In your case, you could use this snippet of code to avoid them:

```
Car car = dao.getCar();
Optional<Car> optionalCar = Optional.ofNullable(car); 
Optional<Power> optionalPower = getPowerIfPresent(optionalCar);

Power power = Optional.empty();
if(optionalPower.isPresent()) {
    power = optionalPower.get();
}
```

after writing a function that returns the `power` of a given `car`:

```
public static Optional<Power> getPowerIfPresent(Optional<Car> car) {
    return car
        .flatMap(c -> c.getEngine())
        .map(e -> e.getPower());
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! But it does not seem to be generic enough. I mean, I still need to create a lot of methods: getPowerIfPresent, getColorIfPresent, getEngineLeftPanelNumberOfBoltsIfPresent ...

Comment: No problem, it's just that your question didn't state this very explicitly in the first place or I might have over-simplified it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as using of `Optional`, but might be more readable:

```
public class NullSafe<T> {
    private final T value;
    public NullSafe(@Nullable T value) { this.value = value; }
    public static <T> NullSafe<T> of(@Nullable T value) { return new NullSafe<>(value); }

    public <R> NullSafe<R> get(Function<T,R> mapper) {
        R newValue = (value != null) ? mapper.apply(value) : null;
        return new NullSafe<>(newValue);
    }

    public T nullable() { return value; }
    public T orDefault(T defaultValue) { return (value != null) ? value : defaultValue; }
}
```

And usage:

```
Power power = NullSafe.of(dao.getCar())
    .get(Car::getEngine)
    .get(Engine::getPower)
    .nullable(); // .orDefault(Power.defaultPower());
```

An alternative can be static methods:

```
public static <R> R get(Supplier<R> supplier, R defaultValue) {
    try {  return supplier.get(); } 
    catch (NullPointerException ex) { return defaultValue; }
}

public static <R> R getNullable(Supplier<R> supplier) { return get(supplier, null); }
```

And usage:

```
Power power = NullSafe.get(() -> dao.getCar().getEngine().getPower(), Power.defaultPower());
Power powerOrNull = NullSafe.getNullable(() -> dao.getCar().getEngine().getPower());
```

Comment: Thank you! I've build the same thing in my project, but without any generic, unfortunately. As I have Java 6 restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe create some util method:

```
static <T> Optional<T> tryGet(Supplier<T> getter) {
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(getter.get());
    } catch(NullPointerException ignored) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
System.out.println(tryGet(() -> car.engine.power).orElse(new Power()));
```

There is a library [no-exception](https://noexception.machinezoo.com/) that does that, but you cannot specify it to only "silence" NPEs.

```
Exceptions.silence().get(() -> car.engine.power).orElse(new Power())
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, Sir! This is exactly the answer I've been trying to find!

Answer (score 1):

My own approach kind of this now:

```
public class CarDataExtractor {

   private final Car car;

   private CarDataExtractor(Car car) {
       this.car = car;
   }

  public static CarDataExtractor on(Car car) {
       return new CarDataExtractor(car);
   }

   public EngineDataExtractor engine() {
       return car != null && car.getEngine() != null
               ? EngineDataExtractor.on(car.getEngine())
               : EngineDataExtractor.on(null);
   }

   public Car self() {
       return car;
   }
}

public class EngineDataExtractor {

   private final Engine engine;

   private EngineDataExtractor(Engine engine) {
       this.engine = engine;
   }

   public static EngineDataExtractor on(Engine engine) {
       return new EngineDataExtractor(engine);
   }

   public PowerDataExtractor engine() {
       return engine != null && engine.getPower() != null
               ? PowerDataExtractor.on(engine.getPower())
               : PowerDataExtractor.on(null);
   }

   public Engine self() {
       return engine;
   }
}

...

Power power = CarDataExtractor.on(dao.getCar()).engine().power().self()
```

It is because I am restricted to Java 6...

Comment: I think you're over-engineering this. Just write simple method 'extractPower', which would encapsulate null-checks and this should be enough.

Comment: It is not just about the engine power. In my project there is an a great entity built from XML. And there are hundreds of duplicates with null-checks around the code

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option, you could use, which might be helpful for you if you're using Spring.

If you're not using Spring you would need to add additional [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression/3.0.2.RELEASE) to your project.

Using [Spel](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) you could do:

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(dao.getCar());

Power power = parser.parseExpression("engine?.power").getValue(context, Power.class);
```

In expression `engine?.power` safe navigation operator is being used. In case `engine` is `null`, then the whole expression will evaluate to `null`.

This solution will work on Java 6.

Comment: Thank you! I've never heard about Spell before. But I afraid it can add a significant overhead to the performance, through for some use cases I think its usage is pretty helpful

Comment: Please have a look at this section: [SpEL compilation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-spel-compilation)